# How to retrieve value returned from function?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have model.scan().exec() function that pass data object to handler function. And I want to assign returned value to the variable from outer context. How can I do that?

```
function handler (err, data) {
    return data.Count;
}


await model.scan().exec(handler);
let count = // i want it to be data.Count from handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 function handler (model) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
          model.scan().exec((err, data) => err? reject(err) : resolve(data.Count))
        )
 }


 const count = await handler(model);
```

Answer (score 2):

I do'nt really know what `model.scan().exec()` does, but you might be able to do something like this:

```
await model.scan().exec(() => {
 const result = handler.apply(null, arguments);
});
```

or

```
await model.scan().exec((err, data) => {
 const result = handler(err, data);
});
```